# "less than" with math symbol?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I would like to describe the situation where *Y = X - D* by an English sentence.

If D takes a specific value, say 10 cm, I think you can say that "*Y* is 10 cm less (or shorter) than *X*".

How do you say this with the math symbol *D*? I think saying that "*Y* is *D* less than *X*" is incorrect.

I am writing an academic paper now, so I am glad if you suggest me a sentence available in a formal scene. Thank you!

Comment: You have already accepted but you can say that Y is the difference between X and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each variable represents something, you should refer to what it represents. For example:

Suppose every item on sale has a designated discount amount for VIP customers. If X represents the manufacturer's suggested retail price (MSRP) and D represents the VIP discount, then the actual price Y is computed as follows:

Y = X - D

> The actual price is the MSRP minus the VIP discount.
>
> or
>
> You get the actual price by subtracting the VIP discount from the MSRP.
>
> or
>
> The actual price is "D" dollars less than the MSRP.
>
> or
>
> The MSRP is "D" dollars more than than the actual price.

Answer (score 1):

How about literally transcribing the equation?

> Y is/equals X minus D

And if you're writing an academic paper, the readers shouldn't be surprised by seeing formulas. You don't always need to 'type them out'. It's OK to use them inline (as part of a paragraph) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an academic paper, use the mathematical expression Y=X-D.

If you are talking relatively casually you might say "Y" is "D" less than "X", or "The difference between X and D is Y", or "X is D more than Y" or simply "Y equals D minus X"

If you are speaking you should also not use "Y" but explain in words what that variable represents.  When you do that, the interpretation in spoken words may become clearer.  Eg if "X" is the initial position, "D" is the final position and "Y is the displacement you might say "The displacement is the difference between the initial and final positions"

But in an academic paper you must use the mathematical formulation as this is less ambiguous:  "Y=D-X"